# What does the word "tout" do in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, tout-tous

This is a sentence I'm having trouble understanding:

> Le savon hydratant pour les mains Life Brand avec extrait d'aloès pur
>   hydrate la peau en douceur tout en la nettoyant et laisse les mains
>   douces.

This is the way I'm parsing this sentence; but i don't know what to do with the word "tout":

> **Le savon hydratant pour les mains Life Brand avec extrait d'aloès pur**
>   *Life Brand hydrating hand soap with pure aloe extract*
>
> **hydrate la peau**
>   *hydrates skin*
>
> **en douceur**
>   *in a manner/style of softness*
>
> **tout**
>   *???*
>
> **en la nettoyant**
>   *while/by cleaning it*
>
> **et laisse les mains douces.**
>   *and leaves hands soft.*

Questions:
1) What does the word "tout" mean in this sentence? If I understand correctly, "tout" can be an adjective or adverb. What word(s) is it modifying in this sentence?
2) Does anyone know of a way I could have looked this up online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close when parsing the sentence but the preposition(-like) is actually "tout en", instead of "tout" and "en" as separate words, and means "while", "at the same time", "as well as".

In this particular sentence, "en" used alone could be misleading because it could both mean "by" (expressing the way by which that cream moisturizes the skin) or "while" (expressing the fact that the cream moisturizes the skin AND, at the same time, cleans it).

"Tout en", by contrast, is unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

1) for your sentence, "tout" means "and/while", let me explain:
Life Brand hydrating hand soap with pure aloe extract hydrates skin in a manner/style of softness ***AND/WHILE*** cleaning and leaving hands soft.
2) linguee.fr website should have helped you for such need:
https://www.linguee.com/french-english/translation/tout+en.html